# Не переведена справка в разделе "Репутация и модерация"

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Если зайти в справку в раздел [репутация и модерация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reputation), то там первые два раздела написаны на английском.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]